# Using Mod Rewrite to rewrite a address?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following format:

```
mydomain.com/whois.php?domain=google&ext=com&option=whois
```

and I want use mod-rewrite new address such as:

```
mydomian.com/google.com
```

I use this line, but not work:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]*).([a-zA-Z0-9]+) whois.php?domain=$1&ext=$2&option=whois [L]
```

Plese Help Me

Comment: Please elaborate on "not work". What does happen? (Hint: unescaped period, and lack of `$` subject end marker.)

Comment: Do you use `RewriteBase /`? Also note that you **must** escape "." character.

Comment: mario: Just show blank page!
Tomáš Zato: no! I use just that line!

Answer (score 0):

You need this in your .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+)\.([a-z]+)(\.([a-z]{2}))?$ /whois.php?domain=$1&tld=$2&co=$4&option=whois [NC,L]
```

Note that I made some changes to your regex and variable names.
ext is now tld (Top Level Domain e.g. com)

- added `/` before whois.php. Put the .htaccess file in the same folder with whois.php.
- added variable `co` (country domain) which may or may not have a value.
- made the regex case insensitive with the `NC` flag.
- got rid of the `A-Z`, because it's now case insensitive.
- escaped the dots (`.`) with `\`.
- added `-` to the possible characters in the domain.
- changed from `*` to `+` for the number of characters in the domain, because you expect at least 1 character, right?
- got rid of `0-9` for the top level and country domains.

**Update**

If you don't want the change the URL variables in whois.php to reflect my suggested changes, then I provide this new line, which should work without changes to whois.php

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+)\.([a-z]+)(\.[a-z]{2})?$ /whois.php?domain=$1&ext=$2$3&option=whois [NC,L]
```

Comment: Hi, when I use this lines, show me Error 404. I remove / before whois.php but show blank page again

Comment: Error 404 is page not found, so, it seems you may not have whois.php in the same folder as this .htaccess file.

Comment: When you removed the slash and got a blank page that could mean that it directed you to whois.php, but nothing was displayed. Did you see that I changed the variable names?

Comment: whois.php is my folder, if use this line:
`RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+).com whois.php?domain=$1&ext=com&option=whois [L]` work! But I want use other suffixes (such as: net, org, info and...)

Comment: You aren't reading what I said about the URL variable name changes. You would have to edit your whois.php file to use the new variable names. I assumed you could do that.

Comment: I use your new line, but with / show me Error 404 & without / show blank page!

Comment: Do you have other junk in your .htaccess file? It could mess it up.

Comment: I don't know why it wouldn't work for you. Maybe you have another .htaccess in a parent directory with other stuff in it.

Comment: I dont have any .htaccess in a parent directory :(